# In SwiftUI the scrollview inner UI View's shadow will be cut off by the size of scrollview?

Tags: scrollview, swiftui

After updating the Xcode11 beta3, I found the scrollview inner view's shadow will be cut off at the bound, but it ok in the Xcode11 beta2. I just use the bottom padding for fixing it, but I don't think it's a good solution. Is there any other solutions to fix the problem?

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    ForEach(courses) { item in
                        PresentationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                            CourseView(
                                title: item.title,
                                image: item.image,
                                color: item.color,
                                shadowColor: item.shadowColor
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 40)
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
```

the CourseView() has a shadow modifier, the definition's body just like:

```
var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .color(.white)
                .padding(30)
                .lineLimit(4)
                .padding(.trailing, 50)
            Spacer()
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 246, height: 150)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            }
            .background(color)
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .frame(width: 246, height: 360)
            .shadow(color: shadowColor, radius: 20, x:0, y: 20)
    }
```

I hope the CourseView()'s shadow could display OK, not be cut off by the bound of ScrollView.

Comment: Report this bug to Apple? Please, we're only at beta 3!

Comment: I am trying to resolve this clipping issue too but no luck :/

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Spacer() after and before your horizontal stack. This way your horizontal stack (HStack) will take full height of your scroll view. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for you issue. The solution is use the offset in the next view and overlap it on top of the `ScrollView`. In your case it would look like something like this:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    ForEach(courses) { item in
                        PresentationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                            CourseView(
                                title: item.title,
                                image: item.image,
                                color: item.color,
                                shadowColor: item.shadowColor
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.leading, 40)
                .padding(.bottom, 60)
}
SomeView().offset(x:0, y: -60) // 60 is your bottom padding so we offset by negative 60 to counter it.
```